# iphone sdk : UIWebView crash

Tags: ios, iphone

I have created one UIViewController with `UIWebView` and trying to add as subview to another UIViewController. That causes to crash which sends bad request error.

The code Controller that contains WebView is as follow:

```
@interface WebViewController : UIViewController

@end


@interface WebViewController () <UIWebViewDelegate>
{


    IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
}
@end

@implementation WebViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    webView.delegate = self;
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body>This is html text</body></html>"];
    [webView loadHTMLString:str baseURL:nil];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

    return YES;
}
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

}
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

}
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error{


}
```

Code that implements the WebViewController is :

```
 WebViewController *obj = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"webView"];
    [self.view addSubview:obj.view];
```

Comment: You have to keep strong refrence for  WebViewController *obj so it is not released like   [self addChildViewController:obj];  or making a propert some where that point on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add, the relationship between controller, add this:

```
     [self addChildViewController:obj];
```

In your code is:

```
  WebViewController *obj = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"webView"];
  [self addChildViewController:obj];
  [self.view addSubview:obj.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

`UIViewController` instances are not supposed to be used as simple initialisers and delegates of their `view`s, normally you use one of the UIWindow, UIViewController (or it subclass) methods to present another view controller, in your case using an instance of `WebViewController` as a [child view controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html) seems reasonable:

```
[self addChildViewController:obj];
[self.view addSubview:obj.view];
```